# problem about reprojection

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-9.3

I am a new GIS user, I have some problem can not be solved by myself. I get a shape file generated from an Excel file. at first, my projection is WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48N some data are inside my country but some are out of the country. then I had selected and exported only the ones outside the country and reproject as WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_47N it is perfect. so my question is how could i display the two layers in the same projection( WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48N ) perfectly. it would kind if anyone can help me.

I am using arc gis 9.3

Comment: What software are you using to display the data?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to display both datasets in ArcMap. Whichever layer is added first will set the data frame's coordinate system or you can set it yourself in the data frame properties, Coordinate System tab. The layer that is in the other UTM zone will be projected on-the-fly (in-memory) to the data frame's coordinate system.

If you want to create a new dataset in another UTM zone, use the Project Tool.

If you want to know if someone knows of a coordinate system that's more appropriate for your area of interest / country, you have to tell us more about the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to just merge the two layers using the "Merge"-Tool. Since both datasets are WGS84 transformation is no issue. You can assign WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48N for the resulting dataset (Click on Environments --> Output Coordinates). Hope that helps.